# How do I add a cell to a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

In my storyboard, I have a UITableView. When a button is pressed (action is `createGroup:`), I would like to create a new cell in the table view with the text `@"Cell"` for now. How do I do this? I've looked over many questions, but I can't rally understand any. I need help.

Comment: Please read the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS" in the docs.

Comment: ypu want custom cell?

Comment: But to be more specific...you want to add another row to the stack of tableview cells with a press of the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's normal, besides adding a new row (visually), you need to update your Data Source (the notifications array in this case). The UI is just the visualization of your Data Source. So:

```
[array addObject:@"a new Entry"];

[[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths
                        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

And when you delete:

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths
                        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

Comment: I think I get it now. How do I link the table view to the array?